# Arraylist apend not over writer in text file

Tags: java, arraylist, nio

i'm working on Library program.

removing method work fine.

1st i store Text  on Arraylist and after remove Desire Book from Arralist . 
Again write the arraylist(Book) on text file using the method `writer.write();`

text Before Removing also there and new text also.it look like as:

**Before Removing:**

Book1

Book2

**After Removing Book2:**

Book1

Book2

Book1

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            Admin admin=new Admin();
            Charset charset=Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

            Path Source=admin.createTextFile();
            admin.removeBook(Source,charset);

        }

        private void removeBook(Path source, Charset charset) {
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Book Name For Remove");
            String bookName=input.nextLine();

            try(
                    BufferedReader reader=Files.newBufferedReader(source,charset);
                    BufferedWriter writer=Files.newBufferedWriter(source, charset,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                    ) 
            {
                ArrayList<String> lines=new ArrayList<>();
                String s;
                while((s=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    lines.add(s);           
                }
                for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++){
                if( lines.get(i).contains(bookName)){
                    lines.remove(i);

                }
                }

                //Write after removing
                for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++){
                    writer.write(lines.get(i));
                    writer.newLine();

                }
                writer.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

Comment: What do you think `StandardOpenOption.APPEND` does?

Comment: Do *not* open a reader and a writer to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Without `StandardOpenOption.APPEND` content cann't append, it write file form scratch means empty file then

Answer (score 1):

@RealSkeptic already mentioned it, but the mistake was there from the start.

**DO NOT OPEN A SAME FILE FOR READING AND WRITING AT THE SAME TIME**, unless you are really sure about what you are doing. And this "unless" is a rare occurrence, not to mention the fact that in this case you'd probably use a `FileChannel` instead.

Create a temporary file which will hold the *modified contents*, write the modified content into it, and then rename to the original file.

For instance:

```
final Path src = ...;
final Path dst = ...;

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(src, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(dst, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        if (!line.equals(bookToRemove)) {
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        }
}

Files.move(dst, src, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Why `Files.copy()`, rather than `Files.move()`?